# Return row only if one occurance

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to fetch all the `Id` rows that only has zeroes.

```
    Id | valid
    ---| ------
    1  | 0
    1  | 1
    2  | 0
    2  | 0
    3  | 1
    4  | 0
    4  | 1
    5  | 0
    6  | 1
```

Comment: ["Where"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188047.aspx)

Comment: Group by + having max = 0 or sum = 0  those will do the trick too, left join and not it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID
FROM myTable
WHERE Valid = 0
    AND ID NOT IN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM myTable
        WHERE Valid != 0
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Id has only zeroes that sum of valid would be zero. Here is an example of the code.

```
drop table if exists dbo.Table03;

create table dbo.Table03 (
Id int
, valid int
);

insert into dbo.Table03 (Id, valid)
values (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0), (6, 1);


select
t.Id
from dbo.Table03 t
group by t.Id
having SUM(t.valid) = 0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check to achieve your expected result.

Sample execution with given data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Id int, valid int);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, valid)
VALUES (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0), (6, 1);

SELECT T1.*
FROM @TestTable T1
LEFT JOIN @TestTable T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id AND T2.valid <> 0
WHERE T2.Id IS NULL
```

Result:

```
Id   valid
----------
2    0
2    0
5    0
```

If you want `Id`s only, use `SELECT DISTINCT T1.Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option

```
Select A.*
 From YourTable A
 Join (
        Select ID 
         From YourTable 
         Group By ID 
         Having min(valid)=0 and max(valid)=0
       ) B
   on A.ID=B.ID
```

Returns

```
Id  valid
2   0
2   0
5   0
```